# Creating documentation for functions in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create help documentation for a function in R. I understand that I can do this in an .Rd file which I have here:

```
\name{sum_of_squares}  
\alias{sum_of_squares}  %- Also NEED an '\alias' for EACH other  topic documented here.  
\title{Sum of Squares  }  
\description{  Sum_of_squares produces  number which is the result of the sum of squares of the input vector.  
\usage{  sum_of_squares(x)  }  %- maybe also 'usage' for other objects documented here.  
\arguments{  \item{x}{ a numerical vector of any length  }  }  
\value{  Sum_of_squares returns an integer  which is the sum of all the squares of the input vector.  }  
\examples{  sum_of_squares(x)   }
```

but I do not know how to attach it to the function so that when I type:

```
?sum_of_squares
```

the help documentation comes up.

Comment: Have you created a package?

Comment: My recommendation is to [look into the package roxygen2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html) as it allows you to document your code inline in such a way that will automatically generate the .Rd files and the NAMESPACE file necessary. If you don't have a package for your functions, try [pkgKitten](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/pkgkitten.html).

Comment: The only way the help is going to show up is if you put the function into a package and I second @ZNK's recommendation to use `roxygen2` comments since they make it much easier to get both documentation and some elements of the package structure built at the same time. Along with `pkgKitten`, you could also use the RStudio IDE since it makes creating packages _almost_ painless.